# How to hide test In-App Purchases from Analytics Dashboard?

Tags: testing, in-app-purchase, analytics, dashboard

I have an Android app that uses Firebase/Google Analytics. The app has In-App Purchase and my account is enabled to test it, but these fake purchases appear on the Analytics dashboard, polluting the revenue data. Is there any way to hide this fake purchases data from dashboard?

I've looked in Analytics and Firebase settings, in the Play Console, on the internet and so far I haven't found any intuitive answers